# email sent using Devise::Mailer gets filtered out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails app that uses Devise:Mailer to send out an email. I know the functionality works since when I create a user account with "myemail@hotmail.com" I get a confirmation email and everything is great. HOWEVER, when I create an account with "myemail@sfu.ca" (my university email account), the email doesn't reach my mailbox even though it has been sent properly. It's not in the junk folder either.

I'm using a gmail account to send the email and using SMTP with port number 587. Here are my settings in `development.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'gmail.com',
  :user_name            => 'MYEMAIL@gmail.com',
  :password             => 'password',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
```

}

I'm not sure if this is an issue with the way I'm sending the email, or if the problem is on the email service side (i.e. they block emails that have something fuzzy about them). Is there a way to label your emails as "safe" the same way you would, for example, a java online applet, with a certificate of some sort? or are some mail providers just not be able to accept these emails?

EDIT: 
Added the two lines to `development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

the output I'm getting regarding email is:

```
Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 182.4ms

Sent mail to myemail@sfu.ca (967.5ms)
Date: Sun, 20 Sep 2015 21:51:24 +0000
From: myemail@gmail.com
Reply-To: myemail@gmail.com
To: myemail@sfu.ca
Message-ID: <55ff2a5ca51dc_a953f93e3165664988bc@myproject-123456.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Welcome myemail@sfu.ca!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><a href="http://myproject-123456.nitrousapp.com:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=-PAuFJbLVcaDH-FG6">Confirm my account</a></p>

Redirected to http://myproject-123456.nitrousapp.com:3000/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 1378ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 54.244.95.60 at 2015-09-20 21:51:25 +0000
Cannot render console from 54.244.95.60! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered .bundle/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered .bundle/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 201ms (Views: 198.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

EDIT #2:

resolved the issue. The issue was my `domain` attribute being set to `gmail.com` while I was sending it from `http://myproject-123456.nitrousapp.com:3000/` so the domain had to have been `nitrousapp.com`

New settings are:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'nitrousapp.com',
  :user_name            => 'MYEMAIL@gmail.com',
  :password             => 'password',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the authentication issue google account setting which you created new.

There are some points to check your google account settings -

1. Turn off 2-way authentication in google account.

First find out issue. Add these in your development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Comment: My Account -> Sign in and Security-> 2-step verification... is that it?
it's turned off

Comment: I've added the two lines and posted the output from development.log. Is there anything useful there? I doesn't seem like it, it seems like it thinks email delivery was fine

Comment: Use `deliver_now!` instead of `deliver_now` it will raise the error if  not deliver.

Comment: I don't have a `deliver_now` command in the project, it's part of the sign up behavior. I don't explicitly call it